# Xmonad open terminal in same directory

Tags: xmonad

Is it possible to have Xmonad open a new terminal in the same directory as the active terminal (if the active window is a terminal or a program like vim running in one)? As it is, all my terminals open in `$HOME`. It does not matter to me if this happens if I open a new terminal in a different workspace. This would be a huge productivity gain because otherwise I would have to `cd` all the way up to the directory I am working in.

If this is not possible to do directly using Xmonad, I am interested in alternative solutions to this. The only thing I can think of is to overload PROMPT_COMMAND to write out the current directory to a file and have my `.bashrc` look at this file to determine where to go. But this is a very imperfect solution that would work for many cases, but will leave a good majority incorrect.

Comment: Depends which terminal you are using?

Comment: Urxvt is a little tricky but this feature is built straight into gnome terminal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't messed with the defaults much and `ctrl+shift+n` does it for me.

Comment: I never though of using my terminal's controls to do so (as opposed to X-Monad's controls). This works for me.

Answer (score 2):

That doesn't really answers your question, but I have an alternative that can save your time and solve your problem: [autojump](https://github.com/joelthelion/autojump)

This is a software that saves your habits when navigating between folders in the terminal. Every time you `cd` in a folder, it increase the associated likelihood. For example on my system it has now something like:

```
343368.3820292514   /home/fb
66.1004508305352    /home/fb/documents
65.2439790325514    /home/fb/workspace/MyProject
55.78935025659235   /very/long/path/boring/to/join/Folder
51.78935025659235   /home/fb/master-thesis
49.150383518340945  /usr/share/opencv
43.1282216187962    /home/fb/.dotvim
...
```

Then afterward, when you want to go in a folder, you can give only a part of the name and it will go to the most probable folder that corresponds. Usually the command `j` is associated with autojump. For instance in your case the usage will be as follow.

1. Open a terminal
2. (First time only) Go with `cd` to the folder `/very/long/path/boring/to/join/Folder`
3. Do some work
4. Later, when you need another terminal, open a new one
5. Entering `j fol<ENTER>` will bring your directly to `/home/fb/very/long/path/boring/to/join/Folder`

Of course this only work if the folder you want to join is a folder where you often go.

Comment: That sounds like a cool utility. I'd like to see if there is a utility that pushes a directory that you can pop back later... or if not, create one myself: `pwd > ~/poo` -> `cd \`cat ~/poo\``

Comment: Just ask: `pushd` and `popd` ;-)

Comment: Also to switch quickly between two folders: `cd -`. A common workflow is `cd my/directory/one`, then work on it until another folder is needed: `cd /etc/httpd/`. Then to go back to previous one: `cd -`, what mark current directory as previous, making another `cd -` to switch back to it.

Answer (score 1):

I set the my directory on a per workspace basis. Then all the terminals I open in that workspace open in that directory. This is done using the workspacedir extension:
http://xmonad.org/xmonad-docs/xmonad-contrib/XMonad-Layout-WorkspaceDir.html

Basically I bound a key to changeDir. When I press that key a prompt pops up that allows you to set the directory (with working tab completion).

Answer (score 0):

If you can get PID of shell running in current window you can than do something like executing `urxvt -cd $(readlink /proc/$PID/cwd)` (or something similar for different terminal). Don't know how to get pid of current window in XMonad though.

Answer (score -1):

You could use the X window id from `withWindowSet` and query `xprop` for PID, from which to extract CWD.

I've been using [this approach](http://marcinchmiel.com/articles/2017-09/xmonad-launching-terminal-in-cwd) for some time now (with success), on a Linux machine. It should work on most Unix-like OSes granted you tweak your logic for extracting CWD from PID.